# Printing layer name using label element in Print Composer in QGIS 3.12?

Tags: qgis-3, print-composer, layer-name

I'm trying to print the layer name using a label in print composer in QGIS 3.12.

It's not responding to `layer_property(@layer_id, 'name')`, or `[%layer_property( @layer_id, 'name')%]` or `[%@layer_name%]`. Any suggestions?

I have many layers and just one print layout, it is updating data with current selected layer, but not the layer name, the layout is not printing it.

Comment: `[%layer_property(*, 'name')%]` p.s.: `*` 'layer's name' or 'layer's id', both shall do the job

Comment: Thanks Taras. I'm using the expresion `[%layer_property(@layer_id, 'name')%]` to try to get seleted layer's name. What I get is an empty text box.

Comment: Can you double check your layer's id please, `Properties ... > Variables > layer_id`?

Comment: I have checked. There is a value for each variable: layer, layer_id, layer_name. I'm working in the spanish edition of QGis 3.12

Comment: I changes the QGis 3.12 Language to English. I still gue the same result, an empty text box in Lavel item